# Using self made variables from model classes in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

Hello I am new to ruby on rails, so far I have compleated [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I am now trying to add functionality so that I can email someone a comment as it is posted, which I have working.

The only part I can't seem to get to work is getting my view to recognize a variable I have set up in my comment class (in in the bd).

in the code shown below I am trying to check if an email adress was entered. If it is then it tries to send; if not it posts the comment as usual. I have set up a Boolean to determine if the email was entered. But then in the _comment.html.erb I can not access it. Why is this?

**comment.html.erb**

```
  <p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= comment.attempted.to_str %> <==== this line crashes as attempted is a nil class
</p>

<% if(comment.attempted == true) %>
    <p>
    your email was sent
    </p>
  <% end %>



<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

**_form.html.erb (this is what builds a initial comment)**

```
   <p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= comment.body.to_str %>
</p>

<% if(comment.attempted == true) %>
    <p>
    your email was sent
    </p>
  <% end %>



<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: :destroy

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.attempted = false


    if(!@comment.email.empty?)
    @comment.attempted = true
    if(@comment.email.include? '@')
    UserMailer.comment_email(@comment.email,@comment.body).deliver_now
    end
    end
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
```

For note in _comment.html.erb I can access comment.boby and comment.commenter just fine but attempted is nil. Why is this and how should I fix it?

Comment: As a note `if (x == true)` is almost always a pointless exercise. Either it's true or it isn't. `if (x)` is sufficient.

Comment: I know I was using that just as a test, just in case something else was going wrong.

Comment: If you're doing diagnostics, `comment.attempted.inspect` is the best way to see exactly what's going on. That will show you exactly what you're dealing with, even if it's an empty string that would otherwise be invisible. Calling `to_str` is unusual, `to_s` is preferred almost always.

Comment: Thank you I just tried that. Unfortunately It just returns nil.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, just show "nil" rather than crash. Usually that's a better outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious problem here is you're not saving the changes you've made to the comment.

When it comes time to iterate over the comments that record has, that model is regenerated from the database, it's a separate instance.

The most likely fix is this:

```
# Prepare but do not save a new model
@comment = @article.comments.build(comment_params)
@comment.attempted = false

# ... Stuff that may alter @comment.attempted

# Save the new instance.
@comment.save!
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Thank you, such a basic mistake but i probably never would have caught it. Anyway thanks for the solution and the nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a loop in your method:

def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)

This will call the create function again.
i.e. your code never reaches the assignment on the next line:

@comment.attempted = false

That's why comment.attempted is resolved 'nil' in the view because it is never set in the controller.

I would rewrite it like so:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment.attempted = false

  if(!@comment.email.empty?)
    @comment.attempted = true
    if(@comment.email.include? '@')
      UserMailer.comment_email(@comment.email,@comment.body).deliver_now
    end
  end

  # This line adds the comment instance to the article's comments collection.
  @article.comments << @comment

  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```